# Oracle Wallet Password Issue

Tags: sql, database, security

Is there any limitation on the type of special characters that can be used in passwords while storing them in Oracle Wallet.

I am unable to use special characters in schema passwords if they are to be used via Oracle wallet.

By rules in the org for production environment, passwords need to have special characters. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: What do you mean by **special characters**?

Comment: Special characters like *&^%$#@!?()=÷×+-_|~/

Comment: To the best of my recollection, you must define an alphanumeric password (meaning, digits AND letters mixed), so you don't really need any special character. Do you get an error if, for instance, attempt to define the password as `1a2B3c4D`?

Comment: My password has alphabets and numbers caps included. It works fine. when I try to use special characters like @#$%& the wallet stores the passwords but doesn't connect to the database. Gives a password error.

Comment: @YavnicaSaini, how you add password to wallet? If you are using command line tool like `mkstore` please note that command shell may "eat" some characters. All command line tools are batch files. E.g. to correctly process chacter "^" you have to double it so many times how many substitutions are made inside a shell script.